# Can I host customized Ubuntu ISO on my website?

Tags: sharing, custom-distributions, hosting, legal

So I am making a guide on creating custom Ubuntu ISO and I was wondering if I can host a custom image on my website?

I am actually looking to maybe host an image that has `/casper/*` removed and a custom `isolinux.cfg`.

Would that in particular be OK?

But for future reference, can I host a completed customized image?

What would I need to do to be legal?

Comment: You need to rebrand that system if you want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *personally* believe that not only would this not be a problem but there are even some Ubuntu Community Wiki guides to help you along in producing a customised ISO:

- [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)
- [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)
- [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch)

However if you wished to *redistribute* your ISO there would be a few caveats: your ISO could not be called 'Ubuntu' and you could not use Ubuntu or Canonical logos on your product. There are some other issues that can be seen where Canonical asserts its legal rights here:

[Intellectual property rights policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)

and you would do well to read this document thoroughly. But remember that Ubuntu has been altered and redistributed before to create new distros. Some great 'official' examples are:

- Edubuntu: Ubuntu for education
- Ubuntu GNOME: Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop environment
- Kubuntu: Ubuntu with the K Desktop environment
- Ubuntu Kylin: Ubuntu localised for China
- Lubuntu: Ubuntu that uses LXDE
- Mythbuntu: Designed for creating a home theatre PC with MythTV
- Ubuntu Studio: Designed for multimedia editing and creation
- Xubuntu: Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment
- Ubuntu MATE: Ubuntu with the MATE desktop environment

**Reference:**

- [Recognised Ubuntu flavours](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours)

Comment: Good point Mark, I have added in these notes...

Comment: But my Custom Ubuntu ISO boots with the Ubuntu Logo, so if I remove that logo im ok? and/or change the name of the ISO, I am not redistruting a CD lol. I think that to redistrubute would be more customization then Im thinking, Im specifically talking about redistrubuting a Remastersys created ISO. (Note I removed the "try it before you install it screen though) But it still has Ubuntu with the dots when it loads.

Comment: Actually I just read the difference between remastersys backup and remastersys dist is that the dist removes the logos and makes it legit for redistribution   !!

Comment: regarding your comment @FreeSoftwareServers : If you do that you will need to remove -any- reference to "Ubuntu" (so you need to also change the logo in the "help" for instance) and can not refer to "Ubuntu" or "Canonical".

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I will be hosting anything at the moment but I get what your saying it's deeper then just the boot logo

Comment: Even remastersys dist keeps the boot logo it just removes the splash scree, thanks everyone for the clairifications

Answer (score 1):

According to this the anwser is a resounding **NO**

[**Intellectual property rights policy**](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy)

You can redistribute Ubuntu, but only where there has been no modification to it.

I am sure I can host guides, but not any modified ISO

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong exactly here but I am sure that line only applies to distribution under the Ubuntu name, if I modified Ubuntu and called it `my new OS` then it would be fine, you just can't use the Ubuntu brand on a modified version, so not the name and no logos, I guess so you can't tarnish the Ubuntu name if your distro sucks. If you could not redistribute, then how do you explain the hundreds of Ubuntu based OS?

Comment: Yea I understand, but really thats more customization then I planned, I am specifically using remastersys to create a Ubuntu ISO with pre-installed applications, but I am glad this post exists for clarification.